# dynamically created elements not appearing on submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have code which will dynamically create elements which works great.
But I have two forms on my page .. one to load an image and the other to input data which is ordered as follows

```
<form name=image>
</form>

<form name=data>
    <div id="p_scents">
        JavaScript elements are inserted here
    </div>
</form>
```

Now if I have the image form and I submit the form, the javascript created elements are not submitted and do NOT appear in _POST.

But without the image form, these javascript created elements do appear in _POST

Any reason why?

See code below...

```
<table border=1 cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0"  width=80%>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Select image for new banner
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="/index.php/dashboard/create/" enctype="multipart/form-data" name=LoadImage>
                <input type="file" name="image"/>
                <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>

            <form action="index.php/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="CreateBanner">
                <a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
            Give your banner a unique name</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" autofocus /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Specify email address or domain to brand</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="domainName" value="" id="domain" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Status</td>
        <td>
            <select name="status">
                <option value="enabled">Enabled</option>
                <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
            </select>                                                
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Give you banner a default URL</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="url" value="" id="url" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign=top>Alternate Urls
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="p_scents">
            </div>

            <input type=submit>
            </form>                     
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Where's the Javascript?

Comment: Each submit will only include the input fields within it's own form. So if I understand you right and you want both forms submitting together, the easiest solution would just be to combine the two forms into one.

Comment: No both forms  dont have to be submitted at the same time. First the image form.. that will just load an image to the page and then the next form which will submit the data. but when the second form is submitted the javascript created elements dont appear .. but if I view the generated source .. they are there..

Comment: You won't get any help without posting your javascript I guess...

Comment: The Javascript is not the problem.